# How to interactively shows data from store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm new to Vue. I'm trying to interactively shows data from store - my input should be automatically showed in `summary.vue`.

What's I have done so far:

**summary.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="summary-area">
        {{ summaryInfo }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from '../store.js';

  export default {
    name: 'summaryInfo',
    data() {
      return {
        summaryInfo: store.state.input1,
      };
    },
  }
</script>
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
      input1: '',
    },
  mutations: {
    upateState(state, value) {
      this.state.input1= value;
    }
  }
});
```

**input.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="root">
    <el-input placeholder="Please input" v-model="input1"></el-input>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'


export default {
  name: 'NetworksSelector',

  computed: {
    ...mapState(['input1']),

    input1: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.input1;
      },
      set (value) {
        this.upateState(value);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['upateState'])
    },
};
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Console log shows that state is updating correctly, but this changes are not visible in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my problem was with `summary.vue`.

Correct component should looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="summary-area">
        {{ summaryInfo }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from '../store.js';

  export default {
    name: 'summaryInfo',
    computed: {
        summaryInfo: function() {
          return store.state.input1
        }
    }
  };
</script>
```